# Why windows do not alarm when an application hook keyboard

Tags: windows

In microsoft windows , we can simply develop an application that hook the keyboard and mouse or take an screenshot of display.
Why windows do not alarm that a program uses hooking (for example keyboard) ?
Like in iOS , when an application want to access the contacts , gps , microphone or ... , ios alarm that the application want to use devices or data .
Thanks

Comment: yes,that`s it !